# Java - Hibernate Mapping Entity from SQL View One-to-Many

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, one-to-many, hibernate-onetomany

Considering I have the following tables:

```
USERS :
ID - PK AUTO INCR
NAME - CONSTRAINT UNIQUE
AGE

ROLES :
ID - PK AUTO INCR
NAME,
ROLE
```

NAME in TABLE ROLES is NOT a foreign key of NAME from TABLE_USERS as a Role can be held by someone that is not a user.

They both a classic entity mapping:

User.java (+hbm)

```
String id;
String name;
int age;
```

Role.java (+hbm)

```
String id;
String name;
Enum role;
```

How can I have define a view to see for a specific name 1 User and X Role attached to it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_SHOW_BOTH AS
SELECT rownum AS ID, 
        user.name, 
        user.age, 
        role.role 
from USER as user, 
      ROLE as role
WHERE user.name = role.name;
```

**Main issue**: This view is displaying N rows if there's N roles matching the name. How canHibernate convert these results into a List?

I'd like to map the view entity:

ViewBoth.java:

```
String id; // map from column rownum
String name; // map from column user.name 
String age; // map from column user.age
List<Role> roles; // how can the view be converted to a list here in hbm?
```

What should my ViewBoth hbm.xml file specify for List roles if I only want the roles.role column? Or the object Role?

Comment: Did you try `setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(ViewBoth.class))` if you are using `Criteria`? [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/transform/AliasToBeanResultTransformer.html)

Comment: do you try update entity mapping for support one-to-many or create query for receive users with role ?